# Does the topology determine the vector space structure of a topological vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(V, \cdot, +)$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with topology $\mathcal{T}$ and let $0 \in V$ be the zero vector. Is then the linear structure $(\cdot, +)$ on the pointed topological space $(V,0)$ uniquely determined by the topology $\mathcal{T}$ and the distinguished zero element $0$?

If not in general, does this hold, if one specifies further requirements on $\mathcal{T}$, i.e. separation axioms?

Comment: How do you locate the zero vector, given only the topology?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added a clarification.

Comment: More interesting question would be: given two topological vector spaces that are homeomorphic, are they also linearly (continuously) isomorphic?

Comment: @freakish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Kadec_theorem

Answer (score 10):

No, the topology does not determine the vector space structure uniquely.

Consider any homeomorphism $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that fixes $0$; for example, $f(x)=x^3$.

Using $f$, we can define a vector space structure on $\mathbb R$, by using $f$ to "transport" the usual vector space structure:
$$x \oplus y = f^{-1}(f(x) + f(y))
$$
$$r \odot x = f^{-1}(r \cdot f(x))
$$
So in our example with $f(x)=x^3$ we have $1 \oplus 2 = \sqrt[3]{9}$.

The same trick works in any dimension. The point is that a topological vector space can have many nonlinear self-homeomorphisms that fix $0$, and each of those can be used to transport the structure to a distinct vector space structure.

Comment: As you said, preserving the topology is not enough. Preserving a *norm* is enough. Preserving a metric is not enough unless the metric is invariant. Preserving an invariant metric (equivalent to an F-norm) is enough if the space is finite-dimensional; for an infinite-dimensional space the question is, as far as I know, still open.

Comment: Preserving a norm is not enough, one can transport the structure by any homeomorphism that preserves every constant norm surface, i.e. in the ordinary Euclidean norm by any homeomorphism that preserves every circle centered on the origin. Perhaps you meant preserving the norm and the metric it determines? @Peter

Comment: Yes, I did. I was thinking of the Mazur-Ulam theorem and generalisations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology. Note that any $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}$ makes it into a topological vector space.

Now you can put different vector space structures on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0$ is the zero vector.

For instance, take a bijection of $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ sending $(0,0)$ ont $0$ and consider the induced vector space structure on the codomain obtained from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What about, if $\mathcal{T}$ Hausdorff? I add a clarification.

Comment: The definition of topological vector space usually also requires the topology to be Hausdorff - in this case every $n$-dimensional topological vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual topology.